# What does "Blocks your chain on reading and parsing the HTTP request body" mean?

Tags: node.js, restify

I'm reading about Node.JS restify. And under the definition for its function `bodyParser()` it states:

> Blocks your chain on reading and parsing the HTTP request body. Switches on Content-Type and does the appropriate logic. application/json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded and multipart/form-data are currently supported.

I'm confused on what "blocks your chain on reading and parsing the HTTP request body" means. And also confused to what logic it needs to do when switching on content-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it means it will postpone handling the request until the entire request body is read and processed. It doesn't mean that it will be blocking the event loop, just that the request handler (and any middleware between the body parser and the request handler) won't be called. I think it's meant as a reminder that it may take some non-trivial time to read and process large request bodies.

With *"the appropriate logic"* I assume that it will choose the appropriate parser for the content type in which the body is presented (url encoded, JSON, multipart).